# unknown property key found react/no-unknown-propert

Tags: next.js, key, eslint, vercel

When I am uploading my nextjs app to vercel I am getting this error please help me solve it

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 11):

This is an ESLint error, you can disable this specific check.

Checkout my eslint config, I disabled this rule.

```js
//.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true,
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@next/next/recommended",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {
    "react/no-unknown-property": ["error", { ignore: ["jsx"] }],
  },
  globals: {
    React: "writable",
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect",
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure eslint to ignore specific keywords for this rule, eg.

json syntax:

```
...
"react/no-unknown-property": ['error', { ignore: ['css'] }]
...
```

or yaml syntax:

```
react/no-unknown-property:
  - error
  - ignore:
      - 'jsx'
      - 'global'
```

Please see the docs: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue. The error in Vercel log was this:

> Error: Unknown property 'ng-jq' found  react/no-unknown-property

What I did is, in my code file (where I was using a  element with the `ng-jq` property in it), I added the following line at the very top:

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-unknown-property */
```

This resolved the issue. And Vercel didn't threw error after that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ESLint errors. I don't have experience with Vercel, but I am guessing it is building your app for production and treating warnings as errors in the process. If you aren't seeing these errors when running locally, that is probably the case. To help you with the exact issue you need to post the code for Product.jsx around the lines throwing the error.

Comment: this is just an small part of my command prompt I am getting this in almost each files and if i delete key property inside map function of files, another error came is each render should have a unique key property